# The engine node is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, debian, virtual-machine

I am using GCP a virtual machine to be able to consume an api by means of strapi, using this video as a guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMAc7lmKGAA in the description of the video are the commands, when using the command sudo yarn start I get the following error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Ie4.png), I updated the version of node but still appears the error, is there any solution for this?

I searched and found that I had to reinstall yarn after changing the node version, but the error still appears.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.